# Extracting Groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, social-networking

Using Python 3.2 I was hoping to solve the below issue. My data consist of hundreds of rows (signifying a project) and 21 columns. The first of which is a unique project ID and the other 20 columns is the group of people, or person, that led the project. person_1 is always filled and if there is a name in person_3 that means 3 people are working together. If there is a name in person_18 that means 18 people are working together.

I have an excel spreadsheet that is setup the following way:

```
 unique ID person_1      person _2      person_3     person_4   ...  person_20
    12       Tom           Sally          Mike
    16       Joe           Mike
    5        Joe           Sally
    1       Sally          Mike           Tom
    6       Sally          Tom            Mike
    2       Jared          Joe            Mike        John      ...     Carl
```

I want to do a few things:

1) Make a column that will give me a unique 'Group Name' which will be, using unique ID 1 as my example, Sally/Mike/Tom. So it will be the names separated by '/'.

2) How can I treat, from my example, Sally/Mike/Tom the same as Sally/Tom/Mike. Meaning, I would like another column that makes the group name in alphabetical order (no matter the actual permutation), still separated by '/'.

3) This question is similar to (2). However, I want the person listed in person_1 to matter. Meaning Joe/Tom/Mike is different from Tom/Joe/Mike but not different than Joe/Mike/Tom. So there will be another column that keeps person_1 at the start of the group name but alphabetizes person_2 through person_20 if applicable (i.e., if the project has more than 1 person on it).

Thanks for the help and suggestions

Comment: have you seen http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: @dm03514 I have seen it, but could not use it properly to apply it in this case, definitely not because of the objects limitations but my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer gave a clear statement of method, but perhaps you are stuck on either the string processing or the csv processing.  Both are demonstrated in the following code.  The relevant string methods are `sorted` and `join`.  `'/'.join` tells `join` to use `/` as separator between joined items.  The `+` operator between lists in `tname` and `writerow` statements concatenates the lists.  A `csv.reader` is an iterator that delivers one list per row, and a `csv.writer` converts a list to a row and writes it out.  You will want to add error testing to the file opens, etc.  The data file used to test this code is shown after the code.

```
import csv
fi = open('xgroup.csv')
fo = open('xgroup3.csv', 'w')
w = csv.writer(fo)
r = csv.reader(fi)
li = 0
print "Opened reader and writer"
for row in r:
    gname = '/'.join(row[1:])
    sname = '/'.join(sorted(row[1:]))
    tname = '/'.join([row[1]]+sorted(row[2:]))
    w.writerow([row[0], gname, sname, tname]+row[1:])
    li += 1
fi.close()
fo.close()
print "Closed reader and writer after",li,"lines"
```

File `xgroup.csv` is shown next.

```
unique-ID,person_1,person,_2,person_3,person_4,...,person_20
12,Tom,Sally,Mike
16,Joe,Mike
5,Joe,Sally
1,Sally,Mike,Tom
6,Sally,Tom,Mike
2,Jared,Joe,Mike,John,...,Carl
```

Upon reading data as above, the program prints `Opened reader and writer` and `Closed reader and writer after 7 lines` and produces output in file `xgroup3.csv` as shown next.

```
unique-ID,person_1/person/_2/person_3/person_4/.../person_20,.../_2/person/person_1/person_20/person_3/person_4,person_1/.../_2/person/person_20/person_3/person_4,person_1,person,_2,person_3,person_4,...,person_20
12,Tom/Sally/Mike,Mike/Sally/Tom,Tom/Mike/Sally,Tom,Sally,Mike
16,Joe/Mike,Joe/Mike,Joe/Mike,Joe,Mike
5,Joe/Sally,Joe/Sally,Joe/Sally,Joe,Sally
1,Sally/Mike/Tom,Mike/Sally/Tom,Sally/Mike/Tom,Sally,Mike,Tom
6,Sally/Tom/Mike,Mike/Sally/Tom,Sally/Mike/Tom,Sally,Tom,Mike
2,Jared/Joe/Mike/John/.../Carl,.../Carl/Jared/Joe/John/Mike,Jared/.../Carl/Joe/John/Mike,Jared,Joe,Mike,John,...,Carl
```

Note, given a data line like

```
5,Joe,Sally,,,,,
```

instead of

```
5,Joe,Sally
```

the program as above produces

```
5,Joe/Sally/////,/////Joe/Sally,Joe//////Sally,Joe,Sally,,,,,
```

instead of

```
5,Joe/Sally,Joe/Sally,Joe/Sally,Joe,Sally
```

If that's a problem, filter out empty entries.  For example, if
`row=['5', 'Joe', 'Sally', '', '', '', '', '']`, then 
`'/'.join(row[1:])` produces
`'Joe/Sally/////'`, while
`'/'.join(filter(lambda x: x, row[1:]))` and
`'/'.join(x for x in row[1:] if x)` and
`'/'.join(filter(len, row[1:]))` produce
`'Joe/Sally'` .

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to get done, many thanks. One questions and two minor edits. First, the extra '/' does matter and I am having trouble implementing the last line of code for the tname column. The edits, since I prompted that I am using Py 3.2 I changed the print function to match the new style and if anyone wants to get rid of the extra row spaces in the output `,newline=""` can be added after `'xgroup3.csv'`.

Comment: @CJ12, with filter the tname line should look like: `tname = '/'.join(filter(len, [row[1]]+sorted(row[2:])))`.  Regarding extra row spaces in output, I have Python 2.7.3 installed, for which `help(csv)` doesn't mention the newline attribute.  I meant to mention that you might need to set csv dialect attributes, but forgot.  Also, please feel free to accept answer (click the check mark that will appear left of vote-up/vote-down)

Comment: After I play with this a little more, I have one quick question. How can I label (as headers) the outputing columns, let's say group_1, group_2, and group_3, and then keep the unique ID column (the first), but delete the rest (the data that was used to create these groupings?)

Comment: I don't understand the 'quick question', but if you mean to just change the first row written, then add like the following just before `w.writerow(...)` — `if not li: gname, sname, tname = 'g1','g2', 'g3'`.  (If you prefer, write `li==0` instead of `not li`.) If you mean to drop out the person_1 field from all output lines, then in the `w.writerow(...)` line change `row[1:]` to `row[2:]`.  To suppress all the person_* fields, remove `+row[1:]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

1. Export your file to a `.csv` file from Excel
2. Open that input file using python's `csv` module, using `csv.reader`
3. Open another file (output) to write to it using `csv.writer`
4. Iterate over each row in your reader, do your treatment, and write that using your writer
5. Import the output file in Excel

Comment: Greatly appreciate the macro recipe, but I am stuck on step 4 and bringing 3-5 to completion.

Comment: @CJ12 For step 4, once you instantiate a reader, you just iterate over it. For steps 3-5, you can instantiate a writer with `writer = csv.writer(some_file_open_for_writing)`.

Comment: when I try to implement the output I am getting is not what I was hoping to receive, so I guess I may need more help than it seemed. Do you have any examples using code that can get me started so I can apply to my larger dataset?

Comment: @CJ12 You might want to have a look at the examples section in the [`csv` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Still running into trouble. Hopefully someone with some experience with my issue can help use my example as a basis for a solution. Thanks again.